# Draw Rectangle over Image

Tags: .net, wpf, image

I want to draw some [Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle) over a single [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image).

For example I have following (white and black) ship profile, and I want to add some (yellow and red) rectangles over this profile in specific locations:

[image]

Is it possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's very possible, if you know the x, y, width and height of the areas that you want to highlight already you can place all of the controls in to a canvas.

You can set the properties on the rectangles in code behind like this:

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
rectangle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 10);
rectangle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 10);
rectangle.Width = 1000;
rectangle.Height = 50;
rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush() { Color = Colors.Red, Opacity = 0.75f };

canvas.Children.Add(rectangle);
```

and if you want to add them in xaml you can like this.

```
<Canvas>
    <Image Source="..."/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="1000" Height="50">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
           <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.75"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>                        
</Canvas>
```

Comment: He'll also want to make the color with transparency.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the C# and XAML to make the rectange red and slightly transparent.

Comment: Ok, thats great, you can use the C# version, maybe create a method that takes the location, size and color of the rectangle as well as a reference to the Canvas that you want to put the rectangle in to?

Comment: @Andy any idea how to stretch the rectangle with the image as it does not stretch with the image

Comment: you could always put the whole thing in a ViewBox

Answer (score 4):

Try this it also will help you.

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="Multi_Textbox.Window1"
x:Name="Window"
Title="Window1"
Width="640" Height="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image Margin="104,50,75,99" Source="barkship.jpg"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF28B0DE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17.334" Margin="212,0,0,111.333" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="99.667"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="11" Margin="230.667,0,0,115" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="CHANDRU" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="63.333" Foreground="White"/>
</Grid>
```

It's output like this

[image: Result]

Comment: The irony is strong in this one +1