# Canvas position to image pixel

Tags: wpf, image, canvas, pixel

I want to draw rectangles over an image to markup specific regions. 
I saw this question: [Draw Rectangle over Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014182/draw-rectangle-over-image) and it worked. I get a rectangle over the image. Now i want to get the real pixel position on the image. I know i get some data over Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top but where is the relationship between Canvas and image position?

Thanks Lyror

Comment: you could actually draw on the image, better said actually manipulate the bitmap to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you can easily put it in a viewbox like this:

```
<Viewbox> <!-- I will make this construct fit everywhere -->
    <Grid> <!-- I will be exactly the size of the image -->

        <Image Source="/MyImagegeWithResolutionOf1080x720p.jpg"
            Width="{Binding Source.PixelWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            Height="{Binding Source.PixelHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            Stretch="Fill"/>

        <Canvas> <!-- use me to draw your stuff -->
            <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Canvas.Bottom="360" Canvas.Left="540"/> <!-- I will be in the center -->
         </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: This will give you the actual *pixel* position only if the image's DPI is 96.

Comment: he didn't ask more specific I think this will most likely fulfill his needs. Feel free to improve my response

Comment: Or most likely not, nobody knows. I voted to close the question as off-topic because it is missing a precise problem description.

Comment: I do not agree but I guess that can happen in the widths of the interweb...  
For me, it is (especially with the link he provided) clear what he wants to do and that he is not on the level where he started to worry about what a pixel in WPF actually is

Comment: The question says "real pixel position on the image" which makes me think that OP is well aware of that. If they are loading images from their Pictures library to cut out crops or whatever, your approach won't work with images that don't have 96 DPI. Nearly all of the images in *my* Pictures library don't have 96 DPI. Just saying.

Comment: I felt free to improve your post.

Comment: glad you did! Now not only Lyror learned something new but me as well, I didn't know about the `PixelHeight` property. Could you please tell me what exactly this does differently than before as I can't see any change in the output right away? I thought an ImageControl (if not restricted) will always be the size of the picture inside of it.  Will this fix the DPI issue we were talking about?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the online documentation of the BitmapSource class to see the difference between its Width/Height and its PixelWidth/PixelHeight properties.

Comment: sry for my delayed response. I tried it and it works perfectly. Thanks guys